# Listening practice for long vs. short vowels

Tags: pronunciation, resource, vowel-length

I'm looking for good resources or exercises for practicing *recognizing* long vs. short vowels. Minimal pair recordings in "quiz" format would be ideal.

I know when reading whether a vowel should be long or short, and if I pay attention I can pronounce them correctly. But reliably *hearing* the difference is still hard for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find various German pronunciation practices via Google, but I found [German pronunciation practice](http://www.clip2go.com/deutsch-englisch/wl_German+pronunciation+practise_2882_0.htm) useful to make a hand in German vowels.

For more information before clicking the link, it includes:

- Pronunciation of German vowels
- Pronunciation of "o" in German
- Pronunciation of "ö" in German
- Short or long vowels in German
- Double vowels' pronunciation in German
- Pronunciation of diphthongs in German
- Pronunciation of "r" following e, o, u, ä, ö, ü
- Pronouncing "e" in the last syllable
- Pronunciation of "ch" in German

And each part is completed by a good list of examples which can be played, you can see the translation of words by moving the cursor over the word.