# What's the quality of clip2go?

Tags: learning, online-resource

[Here](http://www.clip2go.com/deutsch-englisch) seems to be a neat site.  I like the real samples from (I assuming) real Germans...or at least people fluent in German.

But I'm always concerned with learning a new language from a system that is wrong in how they teach.

Opinions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is a little vague for this site. Try specifying exactly what you want opinions of. For example: "Does the pronunciation sound native?" or "Are the texts written in colloquial or formal language? Are the texts correct?"

Comment: [Related](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/listening-practice-for-long-vs-short-vowels/1461#1461).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about didacts, especially teaching foreign languages. But i'm not sure whether there's really a "system" behind that site. It mainly offers translations, some sort of "language in context / in action". This makes it easier for someone who already has some acquaintance with the foreign language to broaden his/her knowledge regarding vocabulary and formulations.

But grammar seems to lack completely. The focus of that site is vocabulary and "multimedia" learning, seeing and listening a certain word or phrase in different situations and circumstances. This may aid vocabulary memorization, but i fear the learner will stick to that phrases if that site is his only resource.

So, IMO it's a neat site to **complement** a systematic training, but *not* to **substitute** it.