# Spelling to pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, phonetics

It is said that German spelling is largely phonetic (unlike English spelling), and that there is a fairly reliable set of rules to convert spelling to pronunciation. (Sure, there are some exceptions, but I'm happy with something that works 99.9% of the time.)

Can someone tell me where I can find these rules written down? While I don't want to read a 300 page book on the subject, I do want a detailed set of rules that would work for almost all the words I encounter. Most of the pronunciation guides I find on the internet are not detailed enough.

For example, here are some examples of German pronunciation that I would like such a guide to explain:

- When to use long/short vowels. For example, Hoch is [ho:x] but Post is [pɔst].
- What's the rule for devoicing consonants?
- When to use syllabic consonants? For example merken is [ˈmɛrkn̩] and mittel is [ˈmɪtl̩].
- How to pronounce "er"? It could be a schwa (like in aber [ˈa:bɐ] or Ärger [ˈɛrgɐ]), a [ɛ] followed by a schwa (like in Vergabe [fɛɐ̯ˈga:bə]), or [ɛr] (like in merklich [ˈmɛrklɪç]).
- What's the rule for pronouncing "ch"? Usually it's [x] after back vowels and [ç] after front vowels, but sometimes it is pronounced [ks] like in erwachsen [ɛɐ̯ˈvaksn̩].

If someone can point me to a reference that explains these sort of things, that would be excellent.

Comment: "I'm happy with something that works 99.9% of the time" nope - it's  only let's say 75%. My son just learned reading in school and when reading words, he does not know yet, there is a significant chance he uses a wrong pronounciation.

Comment: See also [this](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/listening-practice-for-long-vs-short-vowels/1461#1461)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at this [guide to German pronunciation](http://www.pauljoycegerman.co.uk/pronounce/index.html). It seems to cover a number of the points you'd like explained.

Comment: It seems that the site is gone.

Answer (score 6):

There is a short but quite concise overview on German pronunciation on [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache). When it comes to more profound details definitions from the [International Phonetic Association (IPA)](http://www.langsci.ucl.ac.uk/ipa/index.html) are recommended.

Pronunciation examples that are found on most online dicitionaries are based on IPA rules using their clearly defined [Phonetic Alphabet](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA).

Here are a few examples of courses to learn peculiar aspects (and rules) of German:

- ["the sound of spoken language"](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/#), University of Iowa
- [Phonetik Interaktiv](http://phonetik.sprachsignale.de/phonetiklernen.html), Institut für Phonetik, JWG-Universität Frankfurt am Main

Comment: The [Wikipedia-article is available in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_phonology) too.

Answer (score 3):

There's also a Wikibook, which isn't complete, but it's summarized and has a few good hints:

[Wikibook – German/Grammar/Alphabet_and_Pronunciation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Alphabet_and_Pronunciation#Deutsche_Aussprache_.7E_German_Pronunciation_Guide)

> A simple method of recognizing whether a vowel is likely to be long or short in a German word is called the Rule of double consonants. If a vowel is followed by a single consonant — as in haben (have) [or] schon (already) — the vowel sound is usually long. If there are two or more consonants following the vowel — as in falsch (false) [or] immer (always) — the vowel sound is usually short. […]